# Compare paths in texboxes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, textbox

I have a couple of textboxes in my WinForm.  Then I insert some paths to some files in these textboxes - for example:

```
textbox1: C:\Users\File1.txt
textbox2: C:\Users\John\Desktop\File2.txt
textbox3: C:\File1.txt
textbox4: D:\Stuff\File3.txt
.
.
.
```

I'm trying to check:

1. If each file exists (e.g. maybe `File3.txt` does not exist in this case).
2. If any of the files have the same name (e.g. `File1.txt` in this case).

How can I do this with the least amount of code?  My code is way way too long for this kind of thing.

This is what I came up for checking if files exist. And I have no idea how to start dealing with duplicated file.

```
int filesDontExist = 0;

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.Text))
{   
    if (!File.Exists(textbox1.Text)) { filesDontExist++; }
}

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox2.Text))
{
    if (!File.Exists(textbox2.Text)) { filesDontExist++; }
}

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox3.Text))
{
    if (!File.Exists(textbox3.Text)) { filesDontExist++; }
}

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox4.Text))
{
    if (!File.Exists(textbox4.Text)) { filesDontExist++; }
}

if (filesDontExist == 0) { MessageBox.Show("All files exist!"); }
else { MessageBox.Show("At least one file doesn't exist!"); }
```

Comment: While you should trim it to the minimally necessary code to demonstrate what you have tried, you should share the code that you have.

Comment: Also, if your code *works*, then this is essentially a code-review question, which runs the risk of being closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

First get all the paths using LINQ's `Select` method:

```
var paths = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Select(x => x.Text);
```

Then use `File.Exists` to determine whether all files exists:

```
var allFilesExist = paths.All(File.Exists);
```

And get all file names using `Path.GetFileName` method then check if there are duplicates using `GroupBy`:

```
var isDuplicate = paths.Select(x => Path.GetFileName(x))
                  .GroupBy(x => x)
                  .Any(g => g.Count() > 1);
```

Comment: None of that works. allFilesExist always gives me true no matter what I write in textboxes, and IsDuplicate always gives me false, even if I put two same files in textboxes

Comment: this code will work if your textboxes are direct child of your Form. If they are inside of another container you need to use Controls collection of that container.

Comment: Oh. I didn't think of that. My textboxes are in 6 different group boxes. Im a beginner in C# so sorry for wanting so many details, but could you show me how can I use that Controls collection.
Thank you!

Comment: @orglce in that case you should use groupBoxName.Controls, if there are more than one groupBox try: `this.Controls.OfType<GroupBox>().SelectMany(x => x.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()).Select(x => x.Text);`

Comment: I am so sorry but I have another problem. These group boxes are on a panel named mainPanel. How can I access just those on that panel?
Thank you so much for your help and patience :)

Comment: @orglce just change `this` with the panel name.

Comment: Now allFilesExist always gives me false and isDuplicate always gives me true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64729/discussion-between-orglce-and-selman22).